# connect and insert into Cassandra using perl

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cassandra

I want to know how to connect to Cassandra using Perl, and insert, select, update etc.

I tried this

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Cassandra:host=localhost;keyspace=nomkeyspace",
    "root",
    '',
    { RaiseError => 1 }
);

my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arratref( "SELECT id, nom" );

for my $row ( @$rows ) {
    print( "ok" );
}

$dbh->do( "insert into resultat (ip, nom) values (?,?)" );

$dbh->disconnect;
```

but it's give me this error

> Can't locate DBD/Cassandra.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::Cassandra module)

thanks

Comment: You never bind values to the placeholder.

Comment: What means `doesn't work`. any error Messages?

Comment: it said " Can't locate DBD/Cassandra.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::Cassandra module) " ,

Comment: Do you have installed this package?

Comment: no, but I have doubt more about  this code , if it can really do the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the reqired perl module `DBD::Cassandra`

You can do this with `perl -MCPAN -e install "DBD::Cassandra"`

Comment: nothing happen when i lunch this cmd line, and the error stays the same

Comment: @KhaledAssandi You are working on Windows, mac or Linux?

Comment: @KhaledAssandi I can not belive that *nothing* happens if you enter the command there must be some output

Comment: im working in Linux (ubuntu) , yes nothing i don't know why , if the module is already installed, so why it give me the error message

Comment: `perl -MCPAN -e install "DBD::Cassandra"` is generally written `cpan DBD::Cassandra`

Comment: Thanks for you all